# How can I add a JSON result to a label?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I'm having trouble retrieving an answer from a JSON request on a C# Windows Form Application. My code looks like this:

On `FormLoad`:

```
try
        { 
            var url = "http://webpage.com/dir/sub/folder/app/app.json";
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

            Printer[] toners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Printer[]>(json);


            foreach (var j in toners)
            {
                lblOpt.Text = j.opt;
                lblStatus.Text = j.status;
                lblRemaining.Text = j.remaining;
                lblCnt.Text = j.cnt;
                lblCapa.Text = j.capa;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

And also I got this method:

```
class Printer
    {
        public string opt { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string remaining { get; set; }
        public string cnt { get; set; }
        public string capa { get; set; } 
    }
```

But when Form is loaded I got the following:

[image: JSon Error]

This is the answer I got from the JSON in the browser:

```
toner_black: {
    opt: 1,
    status: 0,
    remaining: 23,
    cnt: 3488,
    capa: 5000,
    id: "CK670EXP",
    serial: "CRUM-15050630450"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here.

1) You're expecting array while the browser returns single object.

```
Printer[] toners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Printer[]>(json);
```

becomes

```
var toner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Printer>(json);
```

2) The printer properties are hidden within `toner_black` property. So you need yet another class:

```
public class PrinterWrapper {
  public Printer toner_black { get; set; }
}
```

3) Your `Printer` class should be `public` - `public class Printer { ... }`

Final snippet looks like:

```
var toner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PrinterWrapper>(json).toner_black;
lblOpt.Text = toner.opt;
lblStatus.Text = toner.status;
lblRemaining.Text = toner.remaining;
lblCnt.Text = toner.cnt;
lblCapa.Text = toner.capa;
```

Comment: Good call on the `toner_black` property - I missed that bit in my answer!